# Fitch proof exercise: showing $(\lnot \forall x \; P(x)) \leftrightarrow (\exists x \lnot P(x))$

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I have got a Problem with the following fitch proof excercise:

> $\quad\;\; |$
>
> $\triangleright \quad | \quad ?. \quad (\lnot \forall x  \; P(x)) \leftrightarrow (\exists x \lnot P(x))$

This is how far I got: (Notice: I started from the bottom to the top!)

[image]

My problem is, that I can't find a way how to contradict $P(c)$. My first idea was, to proof $\forall x \; P(x)$ in the subproof in order to get a contradiction.

As you can see, this is only the first part of the proof. I know that I will have to use a Biconditional introduction in the end. I only need help for the first subproof.

Would be great if anyone could give me some hints.

Comment: Welcome to math stackexchange. I have tidied up your question -- we like it when titles are very specific! I hope you find the answers helpful.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will do better next time ;).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me like you are trying to show that $\lnot P(c)$ as a lemma, where you have made no assumptions about $c$. If that were provable, then it would follow that $\forall x ( \lnot P(x))$. But that's too strong -- you only want to show that $\exists x (\lnot P(x))$. (Convince yourself that $\forall x ( \lnot P(x))$ is not necessarily implied by $\lnot (\forall x ( P(x))$, perhaps by thinking of an example set of $x$s and predicate $P$.)

So your dilemma is that you need to get the correct $c$ somehow, in order to prove that $\exists x (\lnot P(x))$; but you only know that $\lnot \forall x. P(x)$, and there's no way to get a $c$ directly from that statement.

In a situation where you get stuck it's good to try proof by contradiction. So, instead of proving $\exists x (\lnot P(x))$ (we have no idea how to get $c$ to make this true), try proving
$$
\lnot \lnot (\exists x ( \lnot P(x))),
$$
by assuming $\lnot \exists x ( \lnot P(x)))$ and getting a contradiction.
The proof structure will look like this:

> 1. $\lnot ( \forall x ( P(x)))$
>
> 2. $\lnot \exists x ( \lnot P(x))$
> 3. ...[fill in here]...
> 4. $\bot$
>
> 5. $\lnot \lnot \exists x (\lnot P(x))$
>
> 6. $\exists x (\lnot P(x))$ (double negation elimination from 5)

But you have to fill in the details for step `3. ...` above.
To do this, show as another lemma there that $\forall x (P(x))$. Proving this lemma will just rely on premise $2$, but may require some more nested reasoning$^1$. Then this lemma will get a contradiction with your original assumption $1$.

$^1$  To prove $\forall x ( P(x))$ we want to start from no assumptions and get $P(a)$. To do this, assume $\lnot P(a)$ and derive a contradiction, thus showing $\lnot \lnot P(a)$, then double negation to $P(a)$.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I managed to find the solution. My fitch program tells me its correct. It was actually way more complex than I thougth.

Comment: @Jenew Yes, this was a messy one. Sometimes you just end up with tons of sub-proofs by contradiction followed by double-negation elimination.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*

You have to start assuming $\lnot Pc$ and $\lnot \exists x \lnot Px$ and find a first contradiction.

Then use *Double Negation* to derive $Pc$ and from it $\forall x Px$ and a new contradiction.

Then, conclude by *Double Negation* again.

Comment: Right. Although it does not address possible issues with the poster's attempted solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof idea is not going to work. Think about it: All you are given is that not everything has property $P$.  However, does that mean that some specific object $c$ does not have property $P$?  No. So, you won't be able to prove $\neg P(c)$

This is often the case when the conclusion is some existential: you have to prove that *some* object has (or lacks) some property, but you won;t be able to point to any specific object and say that that is one of those.

Instead, a potential fruitful approach to prove any existential is to try a proof by contradiction. Below is a completed Fitch Proof using exactly that strategy:

[image]